# Replacing string from dictionary in file

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I've created a file with some words I want to remove from one of my attributes on my dataframe. I charge the file and create a dictionary with key and value:

```
dic1 = dict()
a_file = open("custom-stopwords2.txt")
for line in a_file:
    key, value = line.split(",")
    dic1[key] = value

print(dic1)
```

Then, I remove then from my column:

```
for key, value in dic1.items():
    df["JOB_TITLE"] = df["JOB_TITLE"].str.replace(key, value)
```

But when I want to see if the words have been removed, they are still in the data set:

[Dataset after filtering by words removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl0Ut.png)

Any idea of why it's not removing it? It worked for me before with other files.

Thanks

PS: I can't share the dataset, ;(

Comment: You're probably going to have to show some kind of data here if you want help.  If you can't show the real data, that's fine, just mask it and then include a reproducible example in your question above.

Comment: python string are case sensitive, for example `"Key word".replace("key","new")=='Key word'` so maybe that is your problem

Comment: THANKS! that's was the issue ;( You saved me ;(

Comment: @SofyPond There's a `case` option to `.str.replace()` that can be used to make it case-insensitive.